# MacOS default "Compress Selected Items" is not zip

Tags: macos, zip, textmate

When I select files in TextMate and choose "Compress Selected Items", it will create tbz file. How could I change the default to zip and not tbz?

Comment: This might get more appropriate attention in apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Compress Selected Items* is a command that can be found using:

1. *Bundles → Select Bundle Item…* (<kbd>⌃⌘T</kbd>)
2. Enter `compress`
3. Press option-return (<kbd>⌥↩</kbd>) to edit the item found

On the last line the (just updated version) has:

```
%x{tar -cjf #{dest_path.shellescape} -C #{dest_dir.shellescape}/ #{relative_paths.shelljoin}}
```

Change this line to call zip instead, e.g.:

```
%x{cd #{dest_dir.shellescape} && zip #{dest_path.shellescape} #{relative_paths.shelljoin}}
```

Also change `".tbz"` in line 31 to `".zip"`.